# There are no csrf protections for searchfield in Django Admin by default

Tags: django, security, django-admin, csrf

Our company has some strict rules about security policies. They are doing pentesting for all apps with the vulnerability scanners like Netsparker, Acunetix etc...

Django adds csrf protection for all forms except the search form. It considered by the security team as a vulnerability. Is there a way to add a hidden field or activating csrf protection for the search form?

[image]

Comment: The search form uses a GET request, which is a safe method. The Django CSRF protection is used for unsafe methods, such as POST, PUT, and DELETE.

Comment: Well, now I have to convince them it's not a vulnerability then. Thanks

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115794/should-i-use-csrf-protection-for-get-requests for example